# Clique is NP hard to approximate up to $n^{a}$ for some $a \in (0,1)$

Tags: np-hard, approximation, clique

Given that
$\mathsf{NP}=\mathsf{PCP}_{[\frac{1}{n},1]}\left(O\left(\log n\right),\left(O(\log n\right)\right)$,
show that it is NP-hard to approximate clique up to factor of $n^a$ for some $a \in (0,1)$.

Comment: What is your question (hint: a question ends with a question mark)? What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @orlp I don't know even where to start.
I have no clue? Maybe a reduction?

Comment: What does the subscript mean, every proof for a no instance is accepted with probability at most $1/n$?

Comment: Are you aware of the connection between PCP and gap problems, e.g. the $\delta-GAP-CLIQUE$ problem? Can you tell why a polynomial $\delta$-approximation implies the $\delta$-gap problem is easy?

Comment: shalom @Ariel!
I aware that there is a $\exists\zeta>0.$max-3esat is NP-hard, and that NP=PCP(logn,1), but I don't know how to correlate an interactive proof with an arbitrary soundness.

Answer (score 1):

The $\delta$-GAP-CLIQUE is the following promise problem:

1. yes instances are pairs $(G,m)$ such that $G$ is a graph the contains an $m$-clique
2. No instances are pairs $(G,m)$ such that all cliques in $G$ are of size $<\delta m$

Start by observing that the NP hardness of $n^{-\alpha}$-GAP-CLIQUE implies that max clique is $n^{-\alpha}$ hard to approximate. Now suppose that $SAT\in PCP\left(c_1\log n,c_2\log n, \delta\right)$. Try finding a reduction from SAT to $n^{-\alpha}$-GAP-CLIQUE, i.e. you want to be able to map satisfiable formulas to graphs with a large clique and non satisfiable formulas to graphs where all cliques are small enough. Let $V$ be a non-adaptive PCP verifier with the above parameters for SAT.

The idea is to assign a vertex to every pair $(s,r)\in\{0,1\}^{c_1\log n}\times\{0,1\}^{c_2\log n}$ such that $V$ accepts $\varphi$ given randomness $r$ and answers $s$ to the queries from the proof. We say $(s,r),(s',r')$ are consistent if there exists no $i\le c_1\log n$  such that on randomness $r$ and $r'$ the $i'th$ bit from the proof queried by $V$ is the same, and $s_i\neq s_i'$. Let $G$ be the graph whose vertices are accepting pairs $(s,r)$ for $\varphi$ and two pairs are connected by an edge if they are consistent. The key observation is that a $k$-clique in $G$ is equivalent to the existence of a proof $\pi$ with at least $k$ different random strings $r$ causing $V$ to accept $(\varphi,\pi)$. I leave it to you to fill in the details, namely to show that $\varphi \mapsto (G,n^{c_2})$ is a reduction from SAT to $\delta-GAP-CLIQUE$.